# Crash when trying to add section footer to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to add a section footer to a UICollectionView and failing in a way I don't understand.

I'm setting up the main cell like this:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[PickerOpenCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PickerOpenCell" bundle:nil];
[collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(130, 50);

[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

The xib is a subclass of UICollectionViewCell, and just contains a UILabel.  This all works fine.

Now I want to add the section footer, so I add this (interleaved with the code above, so the setCollectionViewLayout call is still the last one in the sequence):

```
[collectionView registerClass:[PickerOpenFooter class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:footerIdentifier];

UINib *footerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PickerOpenFooter" bundle:nil];
[collectionView registerNib:footerNib forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:footerIdentifier];

flowLayout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(130, 2);
```

The xib this time is a subclass of UICollectionReusableView, and contains a view (it's meant to be a horizontal white line between sections).  The view's size is 130 x 2.

The moment I add the footerReferenceSize line, the app crashes on the setCollectionViewLayoutLine with

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

I have no clue which array this might be, and Google is providing no help.  Any ideas? I must have forgotten to hook something up, but I can't find it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same crash now, but for headers. Your post is the only Google result.

Comment: Sorry, I gave up and put the white line in PickerOpenCell.xib so I could skip having a footer.  It's probably a bug but I didn't have time to report it at the time, and I'd have to remember too many details now. If you report it, leave the  bug number here and I'll dup it.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem. Set a breakpoint at

```
[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

And check if collectionView already as a collectionViewLayout instance property, using the lldb debugger console

```
(lldb) expr collectionView.collectionViewLayout
```

I'm guessing that this is not nil as you would expect, but in fact a UICollectionViewFlowLayout pointer. Most likely you've set the Layout attribute for you Collection View to "flow" in interface builder.

Instead of instantiating another flow layout, just use the one that's already there.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*) collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
```

This fixed the issue for me

Comment: And for me as well. Thanks.